# NVD3.js discrete bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, nvd3.js

I am trying the example given in http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html
And I'm using css and js files given in http://nvd3.org/index.html under **Getting Started**.

Here is my code.

**chartTest1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My First Chart</title>
        <link href="nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg style='height:600px'/>

        <script src="myChart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myChart.js**

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })    //Specify the data accessors.
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .staggerLabels(true)    //Too many bars and not enough room? Try staggering labels.
      .tooltips(false)        //Don't show tooltips
      .showValues(true)       //...instead, show the bar value right on top of each bar.
      .transitionDuration(350)
      ;

  d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(exampleData())
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});

//Each bar represents a single discrete quantity.
function exampleData() {
 return  [ 
    {
      key: "Cumulative Return",
      values: [
        { 
          "label" : "A Label" ,
          "value" : -29.765957771107
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "B Label" , 
          "value" : 0
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "C Label" , 
          "value" : 32.807804682612
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "D Label" , 
          "value" : 196.45946739256
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "E Label" ,
          "value" : 0.19434030906893
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "F Label" , 
          "value" : -98.079782601442
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "G Label" , 
          "value" : -13.925743130903
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "H Label" , 
          "value" : -5.1387322875705
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```

But it gives the following error.

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you solve? Did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at nvd3 live code example, you can see that `transitionDuration` is in `d3.select('#chart svg')` section.

So for fix your problem, you can remove `.transitionDuration(350)` and add `.transition().duration(350)` like this:

```
d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(exampleData())
    .transition().duration(350)
    .call(chart)
;
```

Anyway I make a fiddle with your chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/dqpgq08g/1/

Answer (score 2):

The function `.transitionDuration()` was introduced in August 2013 and was deprecated just five months later. It has been forwarded to `chart.duration()`.

`.transitionDuration()` will just add the property transitionDuration which will do no harm and throw no errors because it is unknown, but will have no effect either. It needs to be changed to `duration` to achieve the desired effect.

http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#discreteBarChart

```
d3.select('#chart svg')
           .datum(data)
           .transition().duration(500)
           .call(chart)
            ;
```